# Install from DVD & Updates of U. 18.04 seemed to have worked but booting off disk sees no GRUB menus and no WIFI

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I confirmed using parted that Windows 10 Partition is still there (Fat32) and Ubuntu is ext4. I get two dark purple screens at boot with no text on them so I can't boot into Windows 10, but I get Ubuntu. Once booted I have no networking, What logs might I examine?

It appears that the installer did apply updates,
so the USB and WiFi drivers in the Install image must have worked, but the wifi part didn't make it onto the HDD. The Keybd and Mouse are USB.

Comment: The Windows 10 partition is NOT FAT32. It's always NTFS. The FAT32 partition is likely to be the ESP (EFI System Partition).

Comment: OK, so parted sees it as fat32, how to I get grub to work with it?

Comment: If there's no NTFS partition your Windows is gone, probably overwrote by the Ubuntu installation and now unlikely to be recovered. Hope you have backups of the personal files you need. OS and programs can be reinstalled anytime.